# How to handle text overflow in plotly js table?

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

Is there any way to apply something like text-overflow: ellipsis to plotly table cell? I want to able to cut the word if its not fit in the cell.

Code:

```
 const dbTableData = [
      {
        type: 'table',
        header: {
          values: [data],
          align: 'center',
        },
        cells: {
          values: [data],
          align: 'center',
          height: 30,
        },
      },
    ];
```

Current problem:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a reproducible example ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/cbsanal/pen/rNKQwRb here is a sample.

Comment: Do you want to cut it or wrap it in the same cell?

Comment: wrap would be better but it is also okay to cut and add ... to end of it

Comment: Cell content already behaves like having style `overflow: hidden; text-overflow: clip;` applied (word is cut, without padding and `align: center` it looks like the text overflows but it doesn't, if you add a leading whitespace and set `align: left` to the cells it is more obvious). It would be better though to shave more options like setting a fixed/min padding and the possibility to wrap (break-word) and/or to add an ellipsis, but there is no easy way to do that with plotly.js. The complicated way would be to do that by hand using d3.